# Excel VBA filtering by cell value on other sheets and using formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

**So I figured out the first part of my question- how to filter by values on other worksheets, the code I used is shown bellow. However, I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong with "average" formula portion**

```
Sub Filtering_Average()
'
' Filtering Macro


'Turn off filtering that has already been applied
Worksheets("Sold Homes").Cells.AutoFilter


Worksheets("Sold Homes").Range("A1").Select

Dim zipcode As Range, bedroom As Range, soldprice As Range
  Set zipcode = Worksheets("Enter Info").Range("B2")
  Set bedroom = Worksheets("Enter Info").Range("K2")
'defining "soldprice" as range that starts in R2 and continues until a blank cell, on sheet "Sold Homes"
    Set soldprice = Worksheets("Sold Homes").Range("R2",     Range("R1").End(xlDown))

'Filtering data in Sold Homes sheet based on zip code and Bedroom count
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$T$15001").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=zipcode
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$T$15001").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=bedroom

'go to the sheet "Enter Info"
Worksheets("Enter Info").Select
'Select cell "AM16"
Range("am16").Select
'Calculate the average of the cells defined by "soldprice"
ActiveCell.Formula = "=Average(soldprice)"


'
End Sub
```

**Question 1 = answered**
I have a workbook with many sheets but the two sheets I am primarily concerned with are Sheet("Enter Info") and Sheet("Sold Homes")

As you may have guessed the "sold homes" sheet holds data on homes that have sold in my area. I have data on 15,000 homes, each in its own row. I need to filter that data by 2 conditions:

**1st** I need to filter the 15,000 rows by the zip code. The zip code is held on "enter info" sheet in cell B2. The zip code is found in Field = 1 on the "Sold Homes" sheet.

**2nd** I need to refine the now filtered data by the number of bedrooms the homes have. The # of bedrooms that a home has is held on the Enter Info sheet in cell K2. The number of bedrooms is found in field = 10 on the "Sold Homes" Sheet.

I know how to write the VBA macro to do a simple filter by zip code and then filter by a specified number of bedrooms but I need the macro to adapt and filter based on what I place into cell B2 and K2 on my "enter info" sheet.

**Question 2**

After the data is filtered on the "sold homes" sheet I need to find the average sale price for the homes that are now showing. The data for the Sale price of each home is found in column "R" of the "sold homes" sheet. The biggest complication of this is that the number of homes returned after the two filtering conditions have been applied varies.

Ex: zipcode 11111, Bedroom count = 3, returns 50 homes. Therefore, I would like the average of those 50 homes

BUT

Zipvode 22222, bedroom count = 4, returns 36 homes.

I would need a way to select only the cells that are in column R that have a Dollar amount in them (Not Blank) for my average function. If I select the entire column R I get the average for every house in the 15,000 home list because filtering does something similar to hiding cells that are not in the selected parameters.

Thanks so much in advance. Sorry I did not post my code the 1st time.

Comment: So what is your question? You got stuck with your program? Please post your code, and be more specific with the question.

Comment: My Problem is that I do not know how to write the macro to reference a cell in another sheet as the cell that holds the value for the zip code to be filtered. The same problem applies to the cell that holds the value for the number of bedrooms. I will post my code once I am back on my work computer. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Filtering_Average()
    '
    ' Filtering Macro
    '
    Dim zipcode As Range, bedroom As Range, soldprice As Range

    With Worksheets("Enter Info")
        Set zipcode = .Range("B2")
        Set bedroom = .Range("K2")
        Set soldprice = .Range("AM16")
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sold Homes")
        With .Range("A1:T" & .Cells(.Rows.count, "R").End(xlUp).Row)
            .AutoFilter 'Turn off any previous filtering
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=zipcode
            .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=bedroom
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then soldprice.Value = WorksheetFunction.Average(.Resize(.Rows.count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 17).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much for helping. I have not had the chance to try this out yet. I will let you know if it works as soon as I get back to my work computer. Why did you use the With/End with at the star of each step? I have never had to use this and dont understand the logic.

Comment: The "With-End With" block lets you assume an object reference (in both cases a worksheet object) and access its members (properties and methods) by means of a simple dot (.). This to both reduce memory accesses and typing burden

Comment: Thank you again. That makes perfect sense.  Could you also explain the logic in the If statement?

Comment: If any cell gets filtered other than in header row then write in soldprice range the average of all filtered cells of the 18th column (17 column offset from the 1st) of referenced range. Does it work?

Comment: that worked perfectly. I just wish I understood how. Thank you for all the help. Is there any way to contact you to understand how the code works? I didnt see a contact or private message button but im new here and could be missing it.

Comment: You are welcome. There's no private message here. The best way to understand a code is to step through it: 1) place your cursor in any statement of the "main" macro 2) press F8 to have macro start 3) the first executable statements gets highlighted and pressing F8 gets you to the following one 4) while "in" a statement you can query relevant variables values by means of the "Immediate Window" (CTRL + G to pop it out) typing such things as `?zipcode` and pressing return. You can also use the "Locals" window (click View -> Locals) to query all variables state.  learn VBA debugging!